# Проблема при сброрке проекта в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я подключил БД mysql к проекту на unity. Само подключение и проект работаеют нормально,но при потыке собрать пакет. выдает ошибку:

ArgumentException: The Assembly Google.Protobuf is referenced by MySql.Data ('Assets/Scenes/MySql.Data.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] cache, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <411aa9fd83b6416fab626ca292954771>:0)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] cache, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <411aa9fd83b6416fab626ca292954771>:0)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <411aa9fd83b6416fab626ca292954771>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)".Не могу понять в чем проблема в интернете тоже не нашел

Answer (score 0):

Что может помочь:

1. Поместить MySql.Data.dll в папку Assets/Plugins, а не Assets/Scenes.
2. В настройках Build Settings->Player Settings->API Compatibility Level установить NET 2.0.

Comment: Попробовал . Ошибка та же ArgumentException: The Assembly Google.Protobuf is referenced by MySql.Data ('Assets/Plugins/MySql.Data.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.

Comment: @Dima, под какую платформу собираешь?

Comment: Под PC windows  10.